# AWS S3 bucket, restrict actions on creating folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-glue

Is there any kind of bucket policy or IAM policy which restricts the user in creation of folders. Ex. Let us consider i have an user - User1, i have provided access to the user to certain folder in the S3 bucket. I need to restrict the user in such a way, that the user can only upload and download the objects. The user should not even have access to create a folder. Can that be done? If it can be done, what should be added and where?(Bucket policy or IAM policy)

Comment: No folder concept in S3. Only bucket and objects are primary resources. In console, its shown in form of folder for organisational simplicity. More details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this on my own, I have a bucket policy which restricts users to only upload a certain type of file. So create folder does not work automatically. The bucket policy i used is mentioned below as reference.

```
    {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1657799010112",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1657798687256",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketforuploadlimitation/Retailer 1/Latest/Start*.gz",
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketforuploadlimitation/Retailer 2/Latest/Dollar/TrendedDetails-Dollar*.xlsx",
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketforuploadlimitation/Retailer 2/Latest/Unit/TrendedDetails-Unit*.xlsx",
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketforuploadlimitation/Retailer 3/Latest/0*.xlsx",
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketforuploadlimitation/Retailer 3/Latest/1*.xlsx",
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketforuploadlimitation/Retailer 4/Latest/Start*.gz",
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketforuploadlimitation/Retailer 5/Latest/Start*.gz",
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketforuploadlimitation/Retailer 6/Latest/TY/Start*.xlsx",
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketforuploadlimitation/Retailer 6/Latest/YA/Start*.xlsx"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1657798687256",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "NotResource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketforuploadlimitation/Retailer 1/Latest/Start*.gz",
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketforuploadlimitation/Retailer 2/Latest/Dollar/TrendedDetails-Dollar*.xlsx",
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketforuploadlimitation/Retailer 2/Latest/Unit/TrendedDetails-Unit*.xlsx",
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketforuploadlimitation/Retailer 3/Latest/0*.xlsx",
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketforuploadlimitation/Retailer 3/Latest/1*.xlsx",
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketforuploadlimitation/Retailer 4/Latest/Start*.gz",
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketforuploadlimitation/Retailer 5/Latest/Start*.gz",
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketforuploadlimitation/Retailer 6/Latest/TY/Start*.xlsx",
            "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketforuploadlimitation/Retailer 6/Latest/YA/Start*.xlsx"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score -2):

There is **no such thing** as "folder" in S3, so you can't prohibit creating something that does not exist. What you see in S3 console as "folder" is just a visual representation of [S3 object keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html) that contain `/` in their name.

Comment: That is all a folder ever is, in any environment, in any context. Folders are just logical representations of a unique name that often contains "/".

Comment: @latj No, because S3 is object store, not a filesystem. Check AWS docs linked.